# how to event listen to any html tag that is clicked within a page, and output the value of its id attribute

Tags: javascript, html, dom, addeventlistener

I want to be able to modify/output to the content of particular header tag with the id attribute value of whichever anchor/link is clicked.

Currently, i am able to only change the text "City" with the value of the first id ("New York", in the below example) - because the text is outside of the nested div tags, but still within the anchor tags. so the first link works, but the 2nd and 3rd links pass empty strings/give no output. i want to the text/content to remain within the div tags as in the 2nd and 3rd links.

```
<base target=splash>

<H3 id=myTitle onclick="myFunction()">City</H3>

<a class="clickable" href="myPage.htm?id=108" id="New+York">New York
    <div class=cityWrap>
        <DIV class=cityNo>108</DIV>
        <DIV class=cityName>New York</DIV>
        <DIV class=country>USA</DIV>
    </div>
</a>

<a class="clickable" href="myPage.htm?id=110" id="Shanghai">
    <div class=cityWrap>
        <DIV class=cityNo>110</DIV>
        <DIV class=cityName>Shanghai</DIV>
        <DIV class=country>China</DIV>
    </div>
</a>

<a class="clickable" href="myPage.htm?id=112" id="Damascus">    
    <div class=cityWrap>
        <DIV class=cityNo>112</DIV>
        <DIV class=cityName>Damascus</DIV>
        <DIV class=country>Syria</DIV>
    </div>
</a>

<IFRAME src="myPage.htm" name=splash></IFRAME>


    <script>
window.addEventListener('load', () => {

let myFunction = event => {
let clickedElem = event.target;
document.getElementById('myTitle').innerHTML = clickedElem.id;
};

for (let elem of document.getElementsByClassName('clickable')) elem.addEventListener('click', myFunction);

});
   </script>
```

Comment: Note that having spaces in your ID may cause problems. For instance, the `href` should be `href="myPage.html?id=New+York"` or `href="myPage.html?id=New%20York"` Selecting the element shouldn't be a problem except if you try to use `querySelector`, in which case you need to escape the space, then escape the escape character, with the usual `#` syntax (`querySelector('#New\\ York')`). I try and avoid spaces in IDs :).

Comment: For this question, I suggest adding a CSS class to the elements that need the event listener.

Comment: thank you for that. am using the CSS class now and will fix the character space issue. your help is much appreciate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Step 1: Add listeners to all required elements

You have a couple of options.

You could exhaustively list all clickable ids in your javascript:

```
let ids = [ 'New York', 'Shanghai', 'Damascus' /* ... */ ];
for (let id of ids) document.getElementById(id).addEventListener('click', myFunction);
```

You could target the clickable elements by the fact that they are all `a` elements:

```
for (let elem of document.getElementsByTagName('a')) elem.addEventListener('click', myFunction);
```

You could attach a common class for all desired `a` elements, and use `document.getElementsByClassName`:

```
html:

<a class="clickable" href="myPage.htm?id=New York" id="New York">New York</A>
<a class="clickable" href="myPage.htm?id=Shanghai" id="Shanghai">Shanghai</A>
<a class="clickable" href="myPage.htm?id=Damascus" id="Damascus">Damascus</A>

js:

for (let elem of document.getElementsByClassName('clickable')) elem.addEventListener('click', myFunction);
```

## Step 2: Determine which element was clicked inside of `myFunction`:

Now the same function, `myFunction`, gets called no matter which element is clicked. We have to figure out which specific element was clicked, to determine which id to display.

Fortunately [Event.target](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target) does this for us. We can rewrite `myFunction` to look like this:

```
let myFunction = event => {

  // Get the <a> element that was clicked
  let clickedElem = event.target;

  // Apply that element's id as the innerHTML of the #myTitle element
  document.getElementById('myTitle').innerHTML = clickedElem.id;

};
```

## Final code

Could look something like this:

```js
window.addEventListener('load', () => {
  
  let myFunction = event => {
    let clickedElem = event.target;
    document.getElementById('myTitle').innerHTML = clickedElem.id;
    event.preventDefault(); // Important to prevent page navigation
  };
  for (let elem of document.getElementsByTagName('a')) elem.addEventListener('click', myFunction);
  
});
```

```css
[href$="=108"], [href$="=108"] *  { background-color: #ffa0a0; }
[href$="=110"], [href$="=110"] *  { background-color: #a0ffa0; }
[href$="=112"], [href$="=112"] *  { background-color: #a0a0ff; }

a > div { pointer-events: none; }
```

```html
<h3 id=myTitle>City</H3>

<a href="myPage.htm?id=108" id="New+York">New York
    <div class=cityWrap>
        <DIV class=cityNo>108</DIV>
        <DIV class=cityName>New York</DIV>
        <DIV class=country>USA</DIV>
    </div>
</a>

<a href="myPage.htm?id=110" id="Shanghai">
    <div class=cityWrap>
        <DIV class=cityNo>110</DIV>
        <DIV class=cityName>Shanghai</DIV>
        <DIV class=country>China</DIV>
    </div>
</a>

<a href="myPage.htm?id=112" id="Damascus">    
    <div class=cityWrap>
        <DIV class=cityNo>112</DIV>
        <DIV class=cityName>Damascus</DIV>
        <DIV class=country>Syria</DIV>
    </div>
</a>
```

Comment: thank you for the above. as there are over 150 or city links, i want to use the options that avoid exhaustively listing them. 

so i tried to incorporate your suggestion, as below, but cant manage to get it working. please excuse my ignorance. am sure am making rookie errors:

js:
 for (let elem of document.getElementsByTagName('a')) elem.addEventListener('click', myFunction);

 let myFunction = event => {

  let clickedElem = event.target;

  document.getElementById('myTitle').innerHTML = clickedElem.id;
};

Comment: It looks like you're referencing `myFunction` before defining it! Move the the `let myFunction = ...` declaration up so it occurs before `for (let elem of document.getElementsByTagName ...`

Comment: ah. thanks. i see it works when i use it stand alone (and i didnt notice the show code nippet function before either). however, it seems to be clashing with something else/some other code i have on the actual page. will try to wittle that down. thanks so much

Comment: hi. i've identified why the script wasnt working with the actual page i was using. as can be seen in the modified question above, my anchor tags nest other div tags. only if i have any text outside of those tags will the script work. but i need to keep the text within the div tags for formatting purposes. any ideas?

Comment: With wrapped divs, `event.target` will be the `div` (and `event.target.id` will be blank). I've updated the "final code" section to set `pointer-events: null` to any `div`s inside of `a` tags - this means you can't click the `div`s, only the `a` tag directly. You can see that solution now works, even with wrapped divs.

Comment: works brilliantly. i am indebted. not sure if its against the rules, but am happy to give $10 or so to your good self as token of my gratitude. i know its not much, but times are hard in lockdown, and its more gesture. either way, thank again.

Comment: I appreciate your offer, but I'm more than happy to settle for the checkmark! I'm not here looking for money :-P

Answer (score 0):

you can try something like this for each of the links

```
<a onclick="getElementById('myTitle').innerHTML = your title here">your value here</a>
```

else try searching for w3schools onclick event
hope this helps :>